# TeXMaker crashes with this TikZ tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, trees

```
\node [rectangle,draw]  at (0,-13) {I:18};
\node [circle, draw] at (2,-13) {19}
    child{node[rectangle,draw] (left node) {S:9}}
    child{node[rectangle,draw] (right node) {M:10}};
\node [circle, draw] at (4, -13) {26}
    child{\node [rectangle,draw] (left node) {A:12}}
        child{\node [circle, draw] (right node) {14}
        child{node[rectangle,draw] (left node) {B:7}}
        child{node [circle, draw] {7}
            child{node[rectangle,draw] (left node) {Z:2}}
            child{node[rectangle,draw] (right node) {X:5}}
        }
    };
```

This chunk of code never allows me to build.  I just wait and wait until my laptop sounds like it's going to die.  I'm using TikZ for tree building.  Can anyone see a mistake in the code?  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Removing the `\` before `node` in lines 6 and 7 should help.

Comment: WOW I can't believe I missed that!  Sleep deprived...Thanks a bunch

Comment: The pretty-printing helps see that!